# 2 layouts nested in a scroll view(one of them a table layout) - Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering is it possible to have 2 nested layouts in android? I have  table layout in a scroll view. I want to add another layout type(not sure which one yet) but everyone I try crashes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
                 android:id="@+id/tblLayout"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            .... rows here ....
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this will crash on the  `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyLayout);`

> "This is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from
>   the current function."

If I just have one layout in the ScrollView it will load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollview documentation is sometimes interesting:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

> Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the
>   user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView
>   is a FrameLayout, **meaning you should place one child in it** containing
>   the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout
>   manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often
>   used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a
>   vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

As they suggest, you should put a LinearLayout that include both of your TableLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the two tables with a Layout like this;

```
<ScrollView>
   <RelativeLayout>   
        <TableLayout>
        </TableLayout>
        <TableLayout>
        </TableLayout>
   <RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```